# Error: Error fetching information for subscription ID, Chainlink Functions

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, subscription, chainlink

I want to use Chainlink functions, for it I need my subscrition.I am using the functions-hardhat-starter-kit from chainlink github documentation. I got indeed a subriction with the PolygonMumbai network. I will put a picture later on this message. The deploying of the contract and the verifying are correct and do not cause a problem. Also in my Subscrition, I have added my Smart-contract as a Consumer. The javascript used in my chainlink Functions is also correct because I do not get an error when I simulate it locally.

When I use this command in my terminal :

```
npx hardhat functions-request --network polygonMumbai --contract 0xae43b7c78f4ee35e1fe07ef3e37a23fb57c78e90 --subid 6323
```

I get this error

```
secp256k1 unavailable, reverting to browser version
[
  'nm7OObrEsTnTL7O//9PQEWzDD8qtp0NPArCxq8ihyMf91LF0ruCp+/hRRuNsf9LZYqXGuVL7pbbSuximFcEy0M1JQtgOeukflorTQywSblru0qY4F6bnJMi0N89YS9F2eY9Z2iNq4PnQmUEBvVBokArCEm3lgQdA+V7WtfW06hgePojyU3OXDHb8zoyD60LaxyWwAQHbNjhpSk8Wc5KzB8c2kMTgBWTLC7RfxF4p3YwJO5FD87GKzDgY/UqmVvQw2h4fc1MIrWQzfMoueTo6/j/cHGNQRixhQIunaZeOsjwVmwJpVZAybq259pz8LUkf64++LHaN5lWmksfIo7LsRA==',
  'dceRAH9cwj86ROjurWfXilIWoJUNaBE775JzLvQDrgFxVamhUrwn7gvsKHD+XXyfRRQQRco5B6g1LSwSpZZO64P6p99EXpiudubxQE3Vwqegt/1igcLzgCvIB7tep2VLYA9dhxevOQZCBh24ChEdZLiiCHfHU4teNISanr3VJGXxyRwGJuhvJFAG8QQIiEsyyCV5nPSsFVAPnN+mes5zpDpRZWSoeGmCQBbthFbbDyzsZ8/5WVrtTsP9ofSfdMuxu46m9/yH3T5FmaCVHbwXBTbgiB5QSbUOuKjdc+D9YebA2ZFFKzrvmiP2w3Ga52PpLobLUXC/XlZsCIQQ+TbyOA==',
  'X1PnkSXjTZ5ZgDwDij97sAuOlR+Or/GD73csmODihMN3U90w3we/7VifGhjmIpMYcZR1DZyVAE6hhSoxcd3eolnRYqMGdzRe5xQjlihOZuxVkEGMyntSetLmjmzEnoxN0cWJAose0OUTS79MNkzeMTimXejutJcNVcTXaXZ0x9yg9nOUtbuIEQTGpEXl24swOLihS8a0e+EVd3c+jvq3WZTOiL0WJW9/GgSrUtq+zoKT4jL/NK+KaRD5bbdNUX5piHr+Ygk/6LNYbn6U1SK31JNoEhEMmhGoiqiykUdBZm3iRQek8MyV3uHLflAiTCTkdb9xu1zExn2t6azbNpEMLw=='
]

Response returned by script during local simulation: 157836e023e37b0e60e5c3bdeaa84f599578544f12b2d78282ca74d482018f7b52,1319b9888f51f56b40302e9408f5a876651c40894eee7a9e98b251c63d027ecce2,1f7f2c65d3bf37d3a7312effe62d5317c15e28e6c9255312a12d50139e16159422

Local simulation of source code completed...
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: Error fetching information for subscription ID '6323':
Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="getSubscription(uint64)", data="0x1f6a65b6", errorArgs=[], errorName="InvalidSubscription", errorSignature="InvalidSubscription()", reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)
```

Honestly I do not know where does it comes from, because I have created my chainlink subscription, I have Link in it, I have Matic on my Wallet, I use the same owner for calling the request in VsCode that the owner in my chainlink subscriton and the chainlink Subscription is on the polygon Mumbai network.

Here is a screenshot of the Chainlink Subscription if it can help :[image]

Any help would be highly appricated

Thank you very much for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

You created a VRF subscription instead of a Functions subscription.

Please head to https://functions.chain.link/ to create a Functions subscription.